# Calculation Ratio's and reversing this ratio on the same measure in powerbi in DAX (without What If Parameter)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I seem to have a very simple issue which you can solve easily with Excel, however unable to do so in Power  BI (except with Edit Interactions and What if Parameter, which is manual work).

So let me explain. My simulation dataset is as follows. I have hotels in different countries, and want to see how these hotels would be staffed if we change the location to any other market. For example, the properties in London, if we would run them at the efficiency of Dubai, how much staff would they need?

[image]

In this case, you could normalize the number of staff by the number of keys for the property. So

```
(Hotel Rooms / Number of Staff) = ratio staff to rooms
```

Multiply this with the new room count, and you get your new staff number. Because you need to use the "Rooms" measure twice with different values I am unable to connect them unless I create a What-if Parameter manually but this creates manual work.

What would be the DAX code to avoid the what-if parameter? if the formula is as follows:

```
(Rooms baseline hotel / number of staff baseline hotel) * Rooms Any other hotel
```

[image]

Comment: Where from the room number comes?

Comment: This is a given

Comment: How do you intend to specify which city to use as a comparison? If it's with a slicer/filter then you're essentially asking how to create a what-if parameter without creating a what-if parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the ratio measure as

```
Ratio = DIVIDE ( SUM ( Data[Room] ), SUM ( Data[Staff] ) )
```

Using this, you can write a specific measure for Dubai

```
DubaiStaffEquivalent =
    DIVIDE (
        SUM ( Data[Room] ),
        CALCULATE ( [Ratio], ALL ( Data[Hotel] ), Data[City] = "Dubai" )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you Alexis, this works if it is only for Dubai, in the dataset that i have i have so many cities that i would like it to be dynamic.

Comment: OK. Dynamic how? How do you pick the city?